# How can I add the external library RainyDay.js to my project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm quite new with React, I just create a project, define a background image and I was wondering how could I use the library https://mubaidr.js.org/rainyday.js/ ? How to add it and what are the good pratice when it comes to add external library in react.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: it looks like it's [available on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rainyday.js), so `npm install rainyday.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This project is not available on npm, so you can't install it like you are used to with other modules. You can include it in a `script` tag, or copy the source to your own project and include it that way.

To use it you can put a `ref` on your image, and create the `RainyDay` object with the image as the `image` option in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  ref = React.createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    const image = this.ref.current;

    image.onload = function() {
      new RainyDay({
        image
      });
    };

    image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    image.src = "https://picsum.photos/200";
  }

  render() {
    return <img ref={this.ref} src="" />;
  }
}
```