# How to use rainyday.js in a React.js project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Has anyone used [rainyday.js](https://mubaidr.js.org/rainyday.js/) in a react.js project? I've found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55089378/how-can-i-add-the-external-library-rainyday-js-to-my-project) about this, but since it was asked the library has become available on npm. I tried to use it as a regular module, but it didn't work for me. Then I did as stated in that question: I copied the source to my project and tried to import and use it, but despite the fact that everything seems to be fine(no errors, everything is visible in inspector) it still doesn't appear to work. How can I fix this?

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import background from '../../resources/backgroundalt.jpg'
import { RainyDay } from './RainyDay'

const Background = styled.div`
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(${background});
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-origin: bottom;
`
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  ref = React.createRef()

  componentDidMount() {
    const image = this.ref.current
    image.onload = function() {
      var engine = new RainyDay({
        image: { background },
        blur: 30
      })

      engine.rain(
        [
          [3, 3, 0.88],
          [5, 5, 0.9],
          [6, 2, 1]
        ],
        100
      )
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <Background ref={this.ref}></Background>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your case is different in 2 ways:

1. You're using `div` with `background-image`
2. You're trying to `engine.rain()` just after you're calling to `RainyDay`

There are few things:

1. `image.onload = function() {` is not relevant because `image` is a `div`, not `img` so `onload` will not fire for it ever.
2. There is a problem in the library so when you run it on an element with `background-image`, the code becomes asynchronous (the library creates a temp `Image` element and listen to `onload`, no important).
3. You're passing an object (`image: {background}`) to the `image` prop instead of passing the image itself (e.g. `image: background`)

So, in order to fix those issues:

1. You should remove the `image.onload` listener and call to `var engine = new RainyDay({` right away.
2. I made a change (in the codesandbox below) in the library's code so it will accept a callback `onInitialized` which will be called only **after** the initialization ended.

So, this is the final code of the component:

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import background from '../../resources/backgroundalt.jpg'

const Background = styled.div`
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(${background});
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-origin: bottom;
`;

export default class App extends React.Component {
  ref = React.createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    const image = this.ref.current;
    var engine = new RainyDay({
      image,
      blur: 30,
      onInitialized: () => {
        engine.rain([[1, 2, 8000]]);
        engine.rain([[3, 3, 0.88], [5, 5, 0.9], [6, 2, 1]], 100);
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <Background ref={this.ref} />;
  }
}
```

You can grab my version of the library, here: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-murdock-1vybm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fpublic%2Frainday.js&theme=dark

Working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/rainday-react-1vybm